# $GLOBALS being cleared in URL included page

Tags: php, superglobals

When I include a page using it's full URL (like `include 'http://mysite.tld/mypage.php'`), I can't use the `$GLOBALS` in `mypage.php`, it returns `Undefined index` error.

But when I include it using it's relative path (like `include 'mypage.php'`), then it's OK.

The reason why am I using URL instead of relative path is that I want to include `$_GET` parameters to `mypage.php`

Is there any logical explanation of this strange behaviour?

---

*Note that both files are on the same server, in the same directory.*

Comment: I assume you mean `$_GLOBALS`, not `$GLOBALS`…

Comment: @JasonMcCreary No. I mean [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php). `$GLOBALS` is the only [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variable that hasn't underscore after the dollar sign.

Comment: I stand corrected. Shows how much I use it… Never - Bad form and or implicit :)

Comment: Why not using $_SESSION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including files with a URL means the code is run as a separate process, which means it runs under a different variable scope. This is as opposed to if you include the file via a relative path, in which case it is pretty much equivalent to cut and pasting the code into the script.

Essentially this means that the only variables available from your starting script are those that you explicitly pass (as you are in this case using the `$_GET` variables). This includes the `$_SESSION` variables, since the caller is your own server rather than the client.

This behaviour is noted in the PHP manual's [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) page:

> If the target server interprets the target file as PHP code, variables
> may be passed to the included file using a URL request string as used
> with HTTP GET. This is not strictly speaking the same thing as
> including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable
> scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the
> result is then being included into the local script.